# Git log - list all merges and direct pushes to master

Tags: git, logging

How do I list all merges and all direct pushes to master branch?
I am not interested in commits that went to master branch with merge.

Comment: "pushes to master" ...what?

Comment: commits pushed directly to master

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for this :

```
git log --first-parent master
```

You can combine it with other `log` options, e.g :

```
git log --oneline --first-parent master
```